# Why this error occuring "TypeError: Series.replace() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given", Where I send 3 arguments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace a `"\\N"` value with `"O"` by pandas.

> But it's showing me this error:

```
df["amount_recived"].replace("\\N", "0", True)
TypeError: Series.replace() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

> My script was:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df1 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/sanyk/Downloads/SM_Data/Data_Set.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/sanyk/Downloads/SM_Data/Data_Set_2nd_part.csv")

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# Less Important column value manipulating
df["amount_recived"].replace("\\N", "0", True)
```

As you can see that there I just sent in `"replace()"` method `"\\N"` as the argument value of `to_replace`, `"0"` as `"value"` and `regex=True`. That means I didn't send anything wrong to the `"replace()"` method. [Official Doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this by removing the True arg in your replace :

```
df["amount_recived"] = df["amount_recived"].replace("\\N", "0")
```

True is your 3rd unnecessary arg

Comment: But even if you could have an additional positional parameter, its default would be False. OP wants inplace, but this doesn't do that.

Comment: Note that this solution will *not* allow you to use a regex for `to_replace`, as the default value of the `regex` parameter is `False`.

Comment: You are right @Nick, it can be worked out like this : `.replace("\\N", "0", regex=True)`. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) on function definitions:

> Parameters after “*” or “*identifier” are keyword-only parameters and may only be passed by keyword arguments.

If you look at the definition of `replace` in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```py
Series.replace(to_replace=None, value=_NoDefault.no_default, *, inplace=False, limit=None, regex=False, method=_NoDefault.no_default)
```

You can see that the `regex` parameter is listed after a `*`, which means it *must* be used as a keyword parameter. So the correct form of your code is:

```py
df["amount_recived"] = df["amount_recived"].replace("\\N", "0", regex=True)
```